# Meteor.publish 2 mongo query results under the same publication?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this publication data:

```
Meteor.publish('privateMessages', function (id) {
    check(id, String);
    return Messages.find({private: true, contextId: this.userId, authorId: id});
});
```

I need this publication to also return:

```
Messages.find({private: true, contextId: id, authorId: this.userId});
```

How do I publish both sets of query results under the same publication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [$or operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/): `return Messages.find({$or: [selector1, selector2]})`

Answer (score 1):

[You can](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-publish) publish documents from multiple collections by returning an array of collection.find results:

```
Meteor.publish("privateMessages", function (id) {
  check(id, String);
  return [
    Messages.find({private: true, contextId: this.userId, authorId: id}),
    Messages.find({private: true, contextId: id, authorId: this.userId})
  ];
});
```

**Attention**: Previous versions (i.e. 0.7.1.2) [restrict](http://devel-docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) you to have different collection in the array.

> If you return multiple cursors in an array, they currently must all be
>   from different collections. We hope to lift this restriction in a
>   future release.

To overcome this limitation you can either use [smart-publish](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/smart-publish) package, or manage the cursors by using 'this.added', 'this.removed', and 'this.changed' inside the publish (as being suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585893/meteor-merging-cursors-of-same-collection)).

Comment: Publish function returned multiple cursors for collection users
Don't think this is allowed in meteor

Comment: @2paws, It is allowed. Look at the second example [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-publish)

Comment: That's weird because it works if it returns 2 queries each querying different collections. But if I do it like you said (which is what I want) it says 'Error: Publish function returned multiple cursors for collection messages'

Comment: @2paws what version of Meteor do you have?

Comment: @2paws, it seems to be solved in the newer versions. I added several solutions for your version.

Comment: I have the latest version. Did a workaround since I need to get a working mvp. thanks for the help!